# $ie.document method is not visible for console page in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, domdocument, getelementbyid, comobject

I am using powershell to automate login page but when i navigate to login console page there is no $ie.document method is visible. and showing the null error. 
Method present for console page are :

CreateObjRef
Equals
GetHashCode
GetLifetimeService
GetType
InitializeLifetimeService
ToString

Code I am using is :-

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible
While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 7;}
$ie.Navigate("https://matlktwlsapp001:16311/ibm/console/")
start-sleep -s 2;
$ie | gm;
$qw = $ie.document.getElementById("overridelink");
$qw.click();
```

Error:- 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

```
At line:7 char:1
+ $qw = $ie.document.getElementById("overridelink");
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At line:8 char:1
+ $qw.click();
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Kindly Help!!

Comment: Unable to repro.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 didn't get you.

Comment: He is saying that he cannot reproduce the issue. Is 2 seconds enough for that to load? You should move the `.busy` line below the `navigate()` line.

Comment: I dont think its delay issue, webpage is getting load within 2 seconds. (I have tried 10 sec too) .

Comment: at line6 , I checked all the method available for $ie. and there is no document method is present. So i am not able to click on the the override button.

Comment: any update on this query ?